# Connection reset on Jersey with Java 7

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to call an https link with the webTarget of jersey 2.22.2.
The code is that:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();

headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("id", id);
headers.add("key", key);

Response response = target.request().headers(headers).get(Response.class);
```

In Java 8 it's work great, but in Java 7 it's give me this Connection reset Exception.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
at br.com.pagador.PagadorRestfulTest.test(PagadorRestfulTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    ... 33 more
```

I finded that should configure the ssl. I've tried everything i've seen but nothing works. The code i've tried in Java 7 using [JerseyWithSSL](https://gist.github.com/JAlexoid/b15dba31e5919586ae51) is that:

```
Configuration config = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().getConfiguration();
Client client = new JerseyWithSSL().initClient(config);

WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();

headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("id", id);
headers.add("key", key);

Response response = target.request().headers(headers).get(Response.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Just find out whats wrong. Java 7 dont allows TLSv1.2. The following code solve my problem:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

public class ClientHelper {

public static Client configureClient() {
    TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };

    SSLContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException e) {

    }

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());

    ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    try {
        clientBuilder.sslContext(ctx);
        clientBuilder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return clientBuilder.withConfig(new ClientConfig()).build();
}
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot for posting the solution, it really helped me

Comment: Its not invoking code inside 'new X509TrustManager()'